# Remove reverse duplicates from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with two columns, `A` and `B`. The order of `A` and `B` is unimportant in this context; for example, I would consider `(0,50)` and `(50,0)` to be duplicates. In pandas, what is an efficient way to remove these duplicates from a dataframe?

```
import pandas as pd

# Initial data frame.
data = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 10, 11, 21, 22, 35, 5, 50], 
                     'B': [50, 22, 35, 5, 10, 11, 21, 0]})
data
    A   B
0   0  50
1  10  22
2  11  35
3  21   5
4  22  10
5  35  11
6   5  21
7  50   0

# Desired output with "duplicates" removed. 
data2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 5, 10, 11], 
                      'B': [50, 21, 22, 35]})
data2
    A   B
0   0  50
1   5  21
2  10  22
3  11  35
```

Ideally, the output would be sorted by values of column `A`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can sort each row of the data frame before dropping the duplicates:

```
data.apply(lambda r: sorted(r), axis = 1).drop_duplicates()

#   A    B
#0  0   50
#1  10  22
#2  11  35
#3  5   21
```

If you prefer the result to be sorted by column `A`:

```
data.apply(lambda r: sorted(r), axis = 1).drop_duplicates().sort_values('A')

#   A    B
#0  0   50
#3  5   21
#1  10  22
#2  11  35
```

Comment: No need for the lambda, `.apply(sorted, axis=1)` will work.

Comment: I love this answer!  Everything I thought up consisted of stacking to dataframes.  This cleverness eliminates that need.

Answer (score 14):

Here is bit uglier, but faster solution:

```
In [44]: pd.DataFrame(np.sort(data.values, axis=1), columns=data.columns).drop_duplicates()
Out[44]:
    A   B
0   0  50
1  10  22
2  11  35
3   5  21
```

Timing: for 8K rows DF

```
In [50]: big = pd.concat([data] * 10**3, ignore_index=True)

In [51]: big.shape
Out[51]: (8000, 2)

In [52]: %timeit big.apply(lambda r: sorted(r), axis = 1).drop_duplicates()
1 loop, best of 3: 3.04 s per loop

In [53]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(np.sort(big.values, axis=1), columns=big.columns).drop_duplicates()
100 loops, best of 3: 3.96 ms per loop

In [59]: %timeit big.apply(np.sort, axis = 1).drop_duplicates()
1 loop, best of 3: 2.69 s per loop
```

Comment: That is the same answer with vectorized implementation.  NOT! uglier :-)

Answer (score 0):

Now this solution works,

```
data.set_index(['A','B']).stack().drop_duplicates().unstack().reset_index()
```

More columns could be added as well as per necessity.
e.g.

```
data.set_index(['A','B', 'C']).stack().drop_duplicates().unstack().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

df.T.apply(sorted).T.drop_duplicates()

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit lengthy solution, but might be helpful for beginners -

Creating new columns for sorting values from Column A & B across row -

```
data['C'] = np.where(data['A']<data['B'] , data['A'], data['B'])
data['D'] = np.where(data['A']>data['B'] , data['A'], data['B'])
```

Removing Duplicates & sorting as per column 'C' as requested in question & renaming the columns

```
data2 = data[['C', 'D']].drop_duplicates().sort_values('C')
data2.columns = ['A', 'B']   
data2
```

PS - "np.where" function works similar to If formula in excel (Logical Condition, Value if TRUE, Value if FALSE)

Answer (score 0):

Another classical option is to aggregate the values as a frozenset and to use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

```
out = data[~data[['A', 'B']].agg(frozenset, axis=1).duplicated()]
```

Output:

```
    A   B
0   0  50
1  10  22
2  11  35
3  21   5
```

It's also fairly efficient, although not as much as the very optimized `np.sort` approach:

```
%timeit big.apply(lambda r: sorted(r), axis = 1).drop_duplicates()
27.2 ms ± 914 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit pd.DataFrame(np.sort(big.values, axis=1), columns=big.columns).drop_duplicates()
733 µs ± 20.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit big.apply(np.sort, axis = 1).drop_duplicates()
12 s ± 403 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit big[~big[['A', 'B']].agg(frozenset, axis=1).duplicated()]
25 ms ± 657 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```